# Static class constructor which is called once per thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm looking for static class constructor which is called once per thread. Something like this :

```
class MyClass 
{
    [ThreadStatic] // This is not working with a method of course. 
    static MyClass() 
    {

    }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve it ?

Comment: A ThreadStatic static instance of a non-static class? That you want it ThreadStatic implies your static class is actually holding state, otherwise it doesn't matter. If it's holding state why is it a static class?

Comment: Can't you create a (static) property and assign a new instance to it? Then make the property Threadstatic?

Comment: @JamesBarrass I remove static class to avoid confusion

Comment: You can have a logic inside method which checks some `[ThreadStatic]` field for `null` and if it's `null` then does something and set field to not-null. This will occurs once for each thread.

Comment: @Reinard : I see what you mean. It should solve this.

Comment: @PabloHoney I added it as an answer, accept it if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [ThreadLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this.  It's similar to using the `ThreadStatic` keyword, but is much more convenient to use when you need to have initialization code per thread, as seems to be your case.

So if you have:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public MyClass() 
    {
        // normal constructor, with normal initialization code here.
    }
}
```

Wherever you are interested in having a separate instance of `MyClass` per thread, you can do the following:

```
ThreadLocal<MyClass> threadSpecificMyClass = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>(() => new MyClass());
```

You can then share `threadSpecificMyClass` between multiple threads, but they will all get different instances when invoking `threadSpecificMyClass.Value`.  And you don't have to worry about checking for `null`, because the initialization happens automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create a (static) property and assign a new instance to it? Then make the property Threadstatic?